# How can I identify correlated subqueries that can not be rewritten as JOINs without using DISTINCT?

Tags: join, subquery

I am fairly new to SQL query tuning. I have been trying to understand how to write equivalent queries. While going through [Prof. J. Widom's Stanford online video lectures, she makes mention that some subqueries that cannot be written by `JOIN`s without the use of `DISTINCT`](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/SQL/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-sql/seq-vid-subqueries_in_where/). For example, see this:

1. 4:45 / 20:13 - GPA example

   ```
   SELECT GPA
   FROM Student
   WHERE sID in (select sID from Apply where major = 'CS');
   ```
2. 6:39 / 20:13 - students applied to CS but not to EE

   ```
   SELECT sID, sName
   FROM Student
   WHERE sID IN (select sID from Apply where major = 'CS')
     AND sID NOT IN (select sID from Apply where major = 'EE');
   ```

My question is how can one know if an SQL statement written using  subqueries will have an equivalent one written using joins. I am quite comfortable, if in the answers, someone likes to use relational algebra notation.

I searched quite a bit on the Net and could not find a suitable answer.

## Sample Data

Schema and table creation (for PostgreSQL) are as follows,

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE college AS
SELECT cname::text, state::text, enrollment::int
FROM ( VALUES
  ('Stanford', 'CA', 15000),
  ('Berkeley', 'CA', 36000),
  ('MIT', 'MA', 10000),
  ('Cornell', 'NY', 21000)
) AS College(cname, state, enrollment);

CREATE TEMP TABLE student AS
SELECT sid::int, sname::text, gpa::real, sizehs::int
FROM ( VALUES
  (123, 'Amy', 3.9, 1000),
  (234, 'Bob', 3.6, 1500),
  (345, 'Craig', 3.5, 500),
  (456, 'Doris', 3.9, 1000),
  (567, 'Edward', 2.9, 2000),
  (678, 'Fay', 3.8, 200),
  (789, 'Gary', 3.4, 800),
  (987, 'Helen', 3.7, 800),
  (876, 'Irene', 3.9, 400),
  (765, 'Jay', 2.9, 1500),
  (654, 'Amy', 3.9, 1000),
  (543, 'Craig', 3.4, 2000)
) AS Student(sid, sname, gpa, sizehs);

CREATE TEMP TABLE apply AS
SELECT sid::int, cname::text, major::text, decision::text
FROM ( VALUES
  (123, 'Stanford', 'CS', 'Y'),
  (123, 'Stanford', 'EE', 'N'),
  (123, 'Berkeley', 'CS', 'Y'),
  (123, 'Cornell', 'EE', 'Y'),
  (234, 'Berkeley', 'biology', 'N'),
  (345, 'MIT', 'bioengineering', 'Y'),
  (345, 'Cornell', 'bioengineering', 'N'),
  (345, 'Cornell', 'CS', 'Y'),
  (345, 'Cornell', 'EE', 'N'),
  (678, 'Stanford', 'history', 'Y'),
  (987, 'Stanford', 'CS', 'Y'),
  (987, 'Berkeley', 'CS', 'Y'),
  (876, 'Stanford', 'CS', 'N'),
  (876, 'MIT', 'biology', 'Y'),
  (876, 'MIT', 'marine biology', 'N'),
  (765, 'Stanford', 'history', 'Y'),
  (765, 'Cornell', 'history', 'N'),
  (765, 'Cornell', 'psychology', 'Y'),
  (543, 'MIT', 'CS', 'N')
) AS apply(sid, cname, major, decision);
```

Comment: You should paste the actual queries here, no one wants to watch the video.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Thanks for adding the detailed queries. After reading your comment, I was about to do it, but you outpaced me!

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, at least not without additional details. The query can be written as:

    `SELECT DISTINCT x.sID, x.sName
    FROM Student x
    JOIN Apply y
        ON x.sID = y.sID
       AND y.major = 'CS'
    LEFT JOIN Apply z
        ON x.sID = z.sID
       AND z.major = 'EE'
    WHERE z.sID is NULL;`

Is this query disqualified due to DISTINCT?

Comment: She says that in the video. So from the lecture, it's qualified because of DISTINCT.

Comment: @Evan Carroll, I did not see the video, I assume you mean disqualified? So the question is really whether JOIN's can result in duplicates in SQL?

Comment: No, the question is *"How can I identified correlated subqueries that can not be rewritten as JOINs without using DISTINCT?"* I updated it. Here is the [video's link](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/SQL/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-sql/seq-vid-subqueries_in_where/) I'll make that more clear in the question.

Comment: I appreciate @EvanCarroll's edit on the title and making the question clearer. In fact, I could not have rephrased it with my current knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how can one know if an SQL statement written using subqueries will have an equivalent one written using joins. I am quite comfortable, if in the answers, someone likes to use relational algebra notation.

Good question.

## First Example Given

So let's look at the first query she gives..

```
SELECT GPA
FROM Student
WHERE sID in (SELECT sID from Apply where major = 'CS');
```

And, then let's look at a similar query with joins,

```
SELECT *
FROM student
JOIN apply ON (student.sid = apply.sid AND major = 'CS');
```

I've changed the columns in  in the first and second intentionally. "GPA" here, is specifically `student.GPA`.

If the following, then the [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) can **not** be rewritten as a *simple* `join`,

1. the `SELECT` statement has aggregates `WHERE gpa in (SELECT max(gpa)..)` (if the join requires aggregation or grouping, you'll have to use a derived or virtual table: `JOIN ( SELECT.. ) AS t`.
2. if the `JOIN` condition is NOT UNIQUE in the above, we assume there is one `student` with a matching row having both a common `sid` and `major=CS`. The resulset can grow *or* shrink of this assumption fails.

You can easily test that..

```
SELECT sid, count(*)
FROM apply
WHERE major='CS'
GROUP BY sid
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

This returns two rows, both `sid`s would get duped in the join.

```
 sid | count 
-----+-------
 123 |     2
 987 |     2
```

As an exercise in clarity, you could push the `DISTINCT` down yourself, and this can again be rewritten using a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT GPA
FROM student
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT sid, major
  FROM apply
) AS apply
  ON (student.sid = apply.sid AND major = 'CS');
```

Or, even..

```
SELECT GPA
FROM student
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT sid, major
  FROM apply
  WHERE major = 'CS'
) AS apply
  USING (sid);
```

## Second Example Given

The second example,

```
SELECT sID, sName
FROM Student
WHERE sID IN (select sID from Apply where major = 'CS')
  AND sID NOT IN (select sID from Apply where major = 'EE');
```

Falls victim to the first example *exactly*. However, the `NOT IN`,

- Doesn't matter for `UNIQUE`-ness because we're excluding results.
- Moreover, rewriting the `NOT IN` as an *anti-join* (`LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON NULL`) is likely faster.
- It will handle any condition where apply.sid IS NULL more effectively, including the case where there are no `major = 'EE'`

Here is an example,

```
SELECT student.sID, sName
FROM Student
LEFT OUTER JOIN apply ON (student.sid = apply.sid AND major = 'EE')
WHERE student.sID IN (select sID from Apply where major = 'CS')
  AND apply.sid IS NULL;
```

## In summary

1. Joins (including `INNER JOINS`) can increase or decrease the amount of rows in the result set.

   1. If the `JOIN` condition is never true, the result on an `INNER JOIN` is pruned.
   2. If the result is true more than once for the same row, the result is that the amount of rows returned increases.
2. But, joins *join* two tables. On `t1 JOIN t2`,

   1. if the `t1`, and `t2` have no duplicate rows then `SELECT t1.*, t2.*` should have no dupes. Something should be different.
   2. If either `t1` or `t2` have duplicate rows then a `JOIN` that includes those row will result in duplicate output rows.
   3. If you `SELECT` a subset of `t1`, or a subset of `t2` (as you did above when you *ONLY* selected GPA) then it's possible to have something that appears to be a dupe, though it's not. Had you have selected `student.GPA, apply.*` you would have seen the reason for the duping.

Comment: Since the OP mentions `Relational Algebra (RA)` as a possible method, it might be worth noting that this will be difficult because RA is based on `SET:s` (where duplicates cannot exist by definition), whereas SQL is based on `BAG:s`.

Comment: I suggest you remove the *"Moreover, rewriting the NOT IN as an anti-join (LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON NULL) is likely faster."* part. Unless you want to add an essay about efficiency, plans and query rewritings, to explain when this is true and when not ;)

Comment: @EvanCaroll, Could you please clarify the first rule, particularly, I could not understand what you meant by "encapsulates only rows from one table."

Comment: @user3686088 tried to make it clearer. Not 100% sure where I was going with that before. I think I was thinking about aggregates.